# Verificar Intervalo entre hora em determinado dia da semana

Tags: php

Ola galera boa noite !

Estou com esse código em php funcionando a função dele é informar se a hora atual esta no intervalo entre 8 as 12

Bom esta funcionando o problema e que preciso que ele informe apenas de segunda a sexta exemplo: se caso for sábado ,ou domingo nao quero exiba nada nem o if e nem o else isso seria possível ?

```
$hora = date('H');

if($hora >= "08" AND $hora < "12"){
   echo "OK";
}else{
   echo "Não ok..";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o próprio `date`:

```
$diadasemana = date('w');

if ($diadasemana != 0 AND $diadasemana != 6) {
    $hora = date('H');
    if ($hora >= 08 AND $hora < 12) {
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "Não ok..";
    }
}
```

Se for `0` é domingo, se for `6` é sábado, então basta colocar o seu if e else dentro de outra if, como está usando o sinal de `!=` (diferente) então entrará no if se for diferente de domingo e de sábado.

> obs: com numeros não precisa de aspas `$hora >= "08"`, basta `$hora >= 08`

Comment: Valeu amigão deu certo !

Comment: Coloquei essa varia vel $diadasemana no lugar das $weekDay deu certo !

Comment: Você foi muit astuto @HemersonPrestes parabéns =) ... Desculpe foi erro de digitação, agora está corrigido